# How can I get iCloud to recognize that I've freed up space

Tags: icloud

This screenshot says it all:

[image: screenshot shows Finder telling me storage is full, and Preferences telling me I have 500M free]

In short, Finder has been telling me for a couple of weeks that my iCloud storage is full, and I should probably buy more. However, I've cleared a lot of stuff out, and just the other day moved 1.2G worth of stuff out of Desktop. iCloud *still* says storage is full, and System Preferences still tells me I have 500Mb free.

How can I tell iCloud to look again, and to start syncing my computer desktops again?

Comment: Try turning off iCloud sync, then clearing things out of iCloud.  When finished, turn it back on.  As always, make sue you have a current back up.

Comment: iCloud tends to keep discards for 30 days. I don't use it so idk where it is, but that would be first place to look.

Comment: iCloud keeps files in the Recently Deleted folder form30 days so you can recover them if needed. If you're sure you won't need those files, empty that folder then wait 24-48 hours for iCloud to synced (leaving the computer connected to power & network).

Comment: I'll look for that folder and empty it and we'll see what happens. If not, turning off and turning it back on again was my second choice. I'd already moved 1.2G of stuff out of iCloud, which turned out to be more work than you'd think, since some of it needed to be downloaded first, and iCloud was being a bit balky about that.

Comment: Hmm. There doesn't seem to be a "Recently Deleted" folder on my Mac. I wonder if that's because I deleted all the files from the command line.